# GLSL: Data Distortion

Tags: glsl, vertex-attributes

I'm using OpenGL 3.3 GLSL 1.5 compatibility. I'm getting a strange problem with my vertex data. I'm trying to pass an index value to the fragment shader, but the value seems to change based on my camera position.

This should be simple : I pass a GLfloat through the vertex shader to the fragment shader. I then convert this value to an unsigned integer. The value is correct the majority of the time, except for the edges of the fragment. No matter what I do the same distortion appears. Why is does my camera position change this value? Even in the ridiculous example below, tI erratically equals something other than 1.0;

```
uint i;
if (tI == 1.0) i = 1;
else i = 0;
vec4 color = texture2D(tex[i], t) ;
```

If I send integer data instead of float data I get the exact same problem. It does not seem to matter what I enter as vertex Data. The value I enter into the data is not consistent across the fragment. The distortion even looks the exact same each time.

[image: Value is not equal to 1.0 along fragment edges]

Comment: Do you really use `tex[1]`, and not `tex[i]` as I think you are using?

Comment: Woops, no I do not. If I use 1 I get the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is *invalid* in OpenGL/GLSL 3.30.

Let me quote the [GLSL 3.30 specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.3.30.6.clean.pdf), section 4.1.7 "Samplers" (emphasis mine):

> Samplers aggregated into arrays within a shader (using square brackets
>   [ ]) can only be indexed with integral **constant** expressions (see
>   section 4.3.3 “Constant Expressions”).

Using a varying as index to a texture does not represent a constant expression as defined by the spec.

Beginning with GL 4.0, this was somewhat relaxed. The [GLSL 4.00 specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.10.6.clean.pdf) states now the following (still my emphasis):

> Samplers aggregated into arrays within a shader (using square brackets
>   [ ]) can only be indexed with a **dynamically uniform** integral
>   expression, **otherwise results are undefined**.

With *dynamically uniform* being defined as follows:

> A fragment-shader expression is dynamically uniform if all fragments
>   evaluating it get the same resulting value. When loops are involved,
>   this refers to the expression's value for the same loop iteration.
>   When functions are involved, this refers to calls from the same call
>   point.

So now this is a bit tricky. If all fragment shader invocations actaully get the same value for that varying, it would be allowed, I guess. But it is unclear that your code guarantees that. You should also take into account that the fragment might be even sampled *outside* of the primitive.

However, you should *never* check floats for equality. There will be numerical issues. I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve here, but you might use some simple rounding behavior, or use an integer varying. You also should disable the interpolation of the value in any case using the `flat` qualifier (which is required for the integer case anyway), which should greatly improve the changes of that construct to become dynamically uniform.

Comment: How might I use rounding make this consistent? I've tried flat integers and I get the same problem.

Comment: @JordanJHiebert: as I wrote. In GL 3.30, this is simply not allowed. What are you trying to do here? Array textures might be an alternative.

Comment: I don't think so. The textures vary in size quite a lot. I also haven't found a very good tutorial on using them. Or one that will explain what the input file actually looks like.

Comment: Do you know of a gl_texture_2d_array tutorial that is helpful and thorough?

Comment: I thought I could get around values being constant. At least this is a good lesson in how texture coordinates are not perfect. Knowing that will help in the future. Back to using gl_VertexID as my index.